# didReceiveNotification not called in NotificationController.m from Watch Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, watchos

I have an app for iOS and watchOS, I'm sending a remote push notification to iPhone where it works properly, but on the Apple Watch I only get the duplicate alert not the real notification, and the method `didReceiveNotification` from `NotificationController.m` is not called.

How can I send the remote notification to watchOS properly?